# General formula for $f_{n}=f_{n-1}^{2}+f_{n-2}^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $f_{1}=1,f_{2}=1$ and $f_{n}=f_{n-1}^{2}+f_{n-2}^{2}$. Can we derive a general(maybe asymptotic) formula for $f_{n}$

Comment: $$2f_{n-2}^2 \le f_n \le 2f_{n-1}^2$$ due to it being an increasing sequence.  Take the natural log of all 3 parts, let $\ln(f_k) = g_k$, solve the resulting 2 affine sequences.  The bounds aren't very tight, but it's a start.

Comment: Maybe ideas from [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/green2/qf.html) could be useful? (a related sequence).  ("Properties of a Quadratic Fibonacci Recurrence,"  Duke, Greenfield, and Speer). See e.g. p.9.

Answer (score 4):

This turns out to be [OEIS A000283](https://oeis.org/A000283); the only formula given is that for $n\ge 1$

$$f_n=\left\lfloor A^{2^{n-1}}\right\rfloor\;,$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
A=1.&235392737785436889622331013228440824347457186913679\\
&454733601897236639743839118542826528455451978134\ldots\;;
\end{align*}$$

no reference is given.

Comment: Any clue where that constant comes from (and if it has some deeper meaning than just "being what it is")?

Comment: @ClementC.: Absolutely none, I'm afraid.